# Toggle menu with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, toggle

I have been racking my brain how I could include a toggle menu on my website, after some searching I found the below and have implemented it, which is great!

http://jsfiddle.net/hhcsz5cr/

```
<div>
<h1><button class="button" data-circle="travel">
<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
</button> Travel</h1>
</div>
<div class="travel options">
<ul>
<li>Travel</li>
<li>Vehicles</li>
</ul>
</div>

var localStorageKey = "app_state";

// to preserve state, you first need to keep track of it
var default_state = {
    biographies: false,
    pictures: false,
    poetry: false
}

var saved_state = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);

// ternary operator which means if `saved_state` is true we parse it and use that value for `state`; otherwise use `default_state`
var state = saved_state ? JSON.parse(saved_state) : default_state;

$(function() {
    init();

    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        var circle = $(this).attr('data-circle');
        toggleCircle(circle, !state[circle]);
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
    });
});


function init() {
    for(var key in state) {
        var is_displayed = state[key];
        if ( is_displayed ) {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
        } else {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-plus');
        }
        console.log(is_displayed);
        toggleCircle(key, is_displayed);
    }
}

function toggleCircle(circle, is_displayed) {
    if (is_displayed) {
        $('.'+circle).show()
        state[circle] = true;
    } else {
        $('.'+circle).hide()
        state[circle] = false;
    }
    
    localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(state));
}
```

But.. if you minimize a menu then refresh the icon shows a - even though its already minimize.
Is there any way I can change this?

I realise the code above is not my own and I can't find the person to credit! My jquery is terrible.

Any help would be appreicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wv0gujp5/) (since SO snippets do not allow localStorage from Iframe)

- Use IDs, not classes. IDs are unique, not classes.
- Store the entire ID as the object property i.e: `"#pictures": false,`
- Store the entire selector inside data-* i.e: `data-toggle="#biographies"`
- Use `"is-*"` classes as state CSS helpers: `"is-hidden"`, `"is-expanded"`
- You don't have to use `.fa` classes, just use CSS and `font-family`
- Make use of [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to override your default values with the ones in Local Storage (if any).
- Loop your object *key value* pairs using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) when initing your menu states.

```js
// Override defaults with localStorage
const state = Object.assign({
  "#biographies": false,  // Feel free to change this default boolean
  "#pictures": false,
  "#poetry": false
}, JSON.parse(localStorage.state || "{}"));

const toggle = (k, v) => {
  $(k).toggleClass('is-hidden', !v);
  $(`[data-toggle="${k}"]`).toggleClass('is-expanded', v);
};

// On init
Object.entries(state).forEach(([k, v]) => toggle(k, v));

// On click
$("[data-toggle]").on("click", function() {
  const id = this.dataset.toggle; // Get ID i.e: "#pictures"
  state[id] = !state[id]; // Flip boolean
  toggle(id, state[id]); // Trigger UI changes
  localStorage.state = JSON.stringify(state); // Store into LS
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}

[data-toggle] i:before{
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  content: "\f067"; /* Plus */
}

[data-toggle].is-expanded i:before{
  content: "\f068"; /* Minus */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="biographies" class="is-hidden">Biography</div>
<div id="pictures" class="is-hidden">Pictures</div>
<div id="poetry" class="is-hidden">Poetry</div>

<button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="#biographies">
  <i></i> biographies
</button>

<button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="#pictures">
  <i></i> pictures
</button>

<button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="#poetry">
  <i></i> poetry
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi there, I don't get this to work for some reason? The menu's aren't opening when you click the button

Comment: @Joe click the fiddle example demo. Works? Great. Compare my code and your code. From HTML, CSS, JS. Happy coding.

Comment: Thankyou. I will have a fiddle with it and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your reply and your answer!

Comment: @Joe I already did it for you. First line in my answer. You're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

**Please try this..**

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
  var whichbtn = $(this).attr('data-circle');
  if($("."+whichbtn).hasClass("hidden")){
    $(this).children("i").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
  }else{
    $(this).children("i").addClass("fa-plus").removeClass("fa-minus");
  }
  $("."+whichbtn).toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
.button{
  background:#00cc00;
  padding:10px 20px;
  margin-right:10px;
  border:none;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="m-3">
  <div class="biographies hidden mb-2 font-weight-bold">Biography</div>
  <div class="pictures hidden mb-2 font-weight-bold">Pictures</div>
  <div class="poetry hidden mb-2 font-weight-bold">Poetry</div>

  <button class="button" data-circle="biographies">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> biographies
  </button>

  <button class="button" data-circle="pictures">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> pictures
  </button>

  <button class="button" data-circle="poetry">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> poetry
  </button>
</div>
```

I add **js** for `click` event of `button` and get the attribute of `data-circle` of it's own for find which button clicked. And `fa fa-plus` icon changed to `fa fa-minus` also. Thats only.
**toggleClass** is used for toggle class when user click the button. First click add class `hidden` then second click remove class `hidden`.**For more clarifications comment me.**

Comment: Please Check @Joe and ensure to compare your expected result with this.
For more clarifications comment me.

Comment: You completely missed the point of storing data into localStorage. Also, learn about the benefits of `.toggleClass()` in jQuery.